# Two newlines in one echo command

Tags: batch-file, line, echo, cmd

Simply put, I've set a most basic text progress indicator in a Windows XP/Windows 7 batch file that writes just after a command line tool's output while it works, because it doesn't look like it does anything for a bit. I do so by piping the blurb after the command as such:

```
app.exe -args "file"|echo Writing "file"...
```

This results in something like the following:

```
_______________
|app for work |  
|ver:2 10/2009|  
|_____________|  
Writing "file"...
```

Is there a way to slip a newline in between the application's output and my output?

Things I've done and failed:

```
|echo.|echo
|echo.|echo.|echo
|echo.&echo.&echo
|echo [alt+255/hex:FF/ÿ/EOL][same again]
|echo -e \r\r (lol)
|echo.. (nope!)
```

The &'s are probably delayed until after the application does its thing, and by then it's too late... Have I missed something? Is it even possible? I know this is not truly important, but I'm very curious.

Comment: Why the heck are you even piping `app`'s output into `echo`? `echo` doesn't take input so that whole construct is rather maeningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I suspect that `app.exe` actually sends its output to standard error, rather than standard output. Otherwise its output would have been sent to the pipe and `echo` would have gobbled it up.

How about this:

```
app.exe -args "file" | (echo. & echo Writing "file")
```

Comment: Yup, that's it! Works perfectly. I don't yet understand the difference between commands in and out of parentheses, but obviously it's important. Thank you muchly for your effort.

Comment: ...it dawned on me. In-parentheses commands are read through to the end, inclusive of separating ampersands within. I knew it all along!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in your case, there are multiple problems.

Normally you can echo a line feed with a small trick

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem Two empty lines are neccessary for the LF creation
rem In the variable <lf> is one line feed character
echo Line1!lf!Line2
------ OUTPUT -----
Line1
Line2
```

But in your case this doesn't work, because the pipe breaks the delayed expansion.

But the pipe will make more problems, as it starts two asynchronous tasks.

In reallity your **app.exe** runs as task1 and **echo Writing file** runs as task2.
So it can happen that task2 will be executed before task1, the output would be

```
app.exe -args "file" | (echo. & echo Writing "file")

Writing "file"...
_______________
|app for work |
|ver:2 10/2009|
|_____________|
```

instead of

```
_______________
|app for work |
|ver:2 10/2009|
|_____________|

Writing "file"...
```

You can test it (on the cmdline)

```
echo one >&2 | echo two
```

In the most cases the output is:

```
one
two
```

But not always!

Comment: I've been wanting to say thank you for this. Sadly, I haven't had enough reputation. Please accept my ethereal vote instead!

Answer (score 0):

you might want to [group](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) your two echo commands:

```
app.exe -args "file" & ( echo ""; echo Writing "file" )
```

Comment: I think the OP is using Windows' cmd.exe

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is this bash language? In Windows batch it waits until the app terminates then prints: ""; echo Writing "file"

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
echo -e "`app.exe -args \"file\"` \n Writing file"
```

Comment: This is all nice and Unix-y, but the OP is using Windows

Comment: Yeah, haha. Maybe the ` syntax transfers?

Comment: Sorry, afaik Windows' echo is barebones. I tried -e as a sanity test.

Comment: The DOS shell is completely different from `sh`. They're both shells and that's about it. It has nowhere near the same capabilities and when it does the syntax is usually completely different.